# Why is my function corrupting only one of my character arrays?

Tags: c, string, null-terminated

```
int main() {
    char str1[21];
    char str2[21];
    char l_str1[21];
    char l_str2[21];

    printf("Please enter the first word: ");
    scanf("%s", str1);
    printf("Please enter the second word: ");
    scanf("%s", str2);

    Lowercase_Strings(str1, l_str1);
    Lowercase_Strings(str2, l_str2);

    printf("Lowercase string 1: %s", l_str1);
    printf("Lowercase string 2: %s", l_str2);

// Converts original strings to lower case, keeping original string unchanged
void Lowercase_Strings(char str[21], char l_str[21]) {
    char c;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i) {
        c = str[i];
        l_str[i] = tolower(c);
    }
}
```

Hey guys/girls! New here so if there's anything wrong with how I formatted this I wouldn't mind the criticism.

This is a snippet from my program to check if two strings are anagrams of eachother, case insensitive.

However, the `l_str1` array always ends up "corrupted" in some way compared to the `l_str2` array, regardless of the order of calling `Lowercase_Strings` or the strings assigned to either array.

For example, `str1 = "MARY"` and `str2 = "ARMY"` will result in `l_str2 = "army"`, but `l_str1 = "mary"` with 2 random symbols at the end.

If anyone has an idea what is going on, it'd be appreciated.

Comment: You forget that all strings in C are *terminated* by the special character `'\0'`.

Answer (score 4):

You are not appending NULL CHAR  to your converted strings.

Add below line at end of your for loop

```
l_str[i] = 0x00;
```

EDIT:

1.Both of the array are not initialized to any value.

2.`printf` will print upto it finds null in the array.

So I can only say here that you are lucky to get null in one of your array at correct position and 2 positions later in second array.
What you did in your code is a undefined behavior and this may result into program crash.

Comment: @vagish, if you don't mind, there is a difference between `NULL` and `null`. Please look into it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
char l_str1[21]="";
char l_str2[21]="";
```

Make sure your strings are `\0` terminated.

I would say

```
 scanf("%s", str1);
```

is not a good idea use fgets() instead.

```
size_t n;
fgets(str1,sizeof(str1),stdin);
n = strlen(str1)
if(n>0 && a[n-1] == '\n')
a[n-1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Actual length of string can be less than 21 and then printf will print random values till it finds NULL CHAR.

Comment: @Vagish whaaat?? [Trolled](http://ideone.com/uyF7f2) Please check few times before DW

Comment: @Gopi: This will not work if the input is taken more than once into same array.

Comment: To ask another question, why did only the l_str1 has that problem, it seems both of them lacked the null character?

Comment: @Vagish Do you know what this means? No need to worry about nul temination of a string in middle of the code. Which is totally fine. `Actual length of string can be less than 21 and then printf will print random values till it finds NULL CHAR. ` This shows that you don't understand my initialization and you go ahead and down-vote

Comment: @Gopi: Sorry, I am not saying this will not work in the mentioned case, I am only pointing out that if he used same array for converting other string input multiple times then he must append null manually if the input string length is not fixed.

Comment: @Vagish Why are you assuming things in all the code where `char array` is used the good way is to initialize it the same as shown in the answer. I would not like to comment on scanning strings in a loop which I don't get where you are getting this assumptions from?

Comment: @Vagish No that is not right. Let's say there is a array `char a[10] =""; size_t n;
fgets(str1,sizeof(str1),stdin);
n = strlen(str1)
if(n>0 && a[n-1] == '\n')
a[n-1] = '\0'; printf("%s",a);`  What ever input you give this code is safe

Answer (score 1):

`strlen()` does not count for the terminating null. So, in the `Lowercase_Strings()` function, after [outside] the `for` loop, you need to add

```
l_str[i] = `\0`;
```

to make sure that `l_str` gets null-terminated.

Also, you may want to limit your input size by using

```
 scanf("%20s", str1);       //read only 20 chars, 1 for null, total 21
 scanf("%20s", str2);       //read only 20 chars, 1 for null, total 21
```